# hyphen in MySQL order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query with this line

```
ORDER BY -order_line_groups.sequence DESC, order_line_groups.id;
```

I'm trying to find out what the hyphen is for just after the order by. I have tried executing with and without it but it does not seem to make a difference. I have also looked at it with explain and cant find anything different.

I was not able to find any MySQL documentation to help. I did find this:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
where the hyphen is listed under "You use ORDER BY with an expression that includes terms other than the key column name:"

It does not give much info. Can someone explain what this does or point me towards some docs?

Thank you.

Comment: @Rahul if that is a typo, it won't get executed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the question:

> I did find this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html where the hyphen is listed under *"You use ORDER BY with an **expression**..."*

The keyword here is **"expression"**. You can use expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
ORDER BY -order_line_groups.sequence DESC
```

is an arithmetical expression and the "hyphen" is not a hyphen but a minus; an unary minus mathematical operator.

#### How it works?

Regarding the outcome, it works as expected:

- If the type of column `order_line_groups.sequence` is a [numeric type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html) or a [date & time type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) (they are internally stored as numbers too) then the minus reverses the order of the returned rows. The clause is equivalent with

  ```
    ORDER BY order_line_groups.sequence ASC
  ```
- If the type of the column is a [string type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-types.html) then MySQL attempts to [convert the values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) of the column to numbers (because the subtraction is an arithmetic operation and it is not defined for strings). When MySQL converts strings to numbers it stops on the first character that is not a digit. Depending on the data you store in column `order_line_groups.sequence`, more or less of its string values will convert to number `0`.

Regarding the speed, as explained in the documentation page provided in the question MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the `ORDER BY`. This makes the query slow.

#### Conclusion

Using `ORDER BY -order_line_groups.sequence` makes the query slow. More, it does not provide a good way to sort the result set when the type of column `sequence` is a string type.

Answer (score 1):

you are negating the value of column 'sequence' and using it in order by ..

```
order by -(number)
```

ordering by negation of a number.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql, you can almost any expression to determine how the data is sorted.    If you do the following example:

```
order by (order_line_groups.sequence*order_line_groups.id)
```

It would calculate the value of sequence*id first.  Then, it would sort the table using those calculated values.

Adding the hyphen to the column you're sorting by basically does this.

```
order by (order_line_groups.sequence*-1)
```

Essentially,  you'll be sorting in descending order.

However, you actually sort that expression descending.

```
order by (order_line_groups.sequence*-1) DESC
```

It would take the descending order sort and reverse it so you have an ascending order sort.

I would recommend that you remove the hyphen and switch DESC to ASC so no one else gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am late,But let me share ordering by  hypen,number and alphabats in your data,

```
SELECT column FROM TABLE
 ORDER BY (column = '0') ASC, (column+0 > 0) DESC, column+0 ASC, column ASC
```