# operator does not exist: - character varying (laravel 8 deployment to heroku)

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my project to Heroku but getting some issues.
When I try to access my site I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist:
> - character varying LINE 1: select * from "categories" order by -name ASC

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30lWp.png)

It's really frustrating as I'm not using any data from the 'categories' table on the homepage or anywhere that the user can reach.
However, I have found this method in CategoryController.php:

```
public function treeList() {
    return Category::orderByRaw('name ASC')
        ->get()
        ->nest()
        ->listsFlattened('name');
}
```

I don't know if that's the place where the error comes from. Please help!

Comment: Your error message will include a backtrace showing exactly where the problem is. Why are you using `orderByRaw()` method?

Comment: You can just use `order('name', 'ASC')` instead of by raw. I've seen the hyphen before a category name on order by, but now I cannot remember where... Edit: it's a [unary minus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659260/hyphen-in-mysql-order-by-clause). Why it's being added, I have no clue, but try it with what I suggested